# Get rid of Conditional statements in try block

Tags: c#, wpf, try-catch

I am building my first WPF application in c#. Below is some part of the code containing try-catch block. But, it has code repetition. Is it possible to have the same functionality without using if-else statements inside try block. Can anyone suggest a better method to do this? Maybe we can throw ArithmeticExceptions, but I am new to all these things and using exception like (1/0) and (1%0) directly gives error.

**Purpose**: Check if the textbox3 contains a 10 digit number or not. If yes, then display that number along with some other data in texbox4. If no, then show an error message.

```
    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            textbox3.Text = (Convert.ToInt64(textbox3.Text)).ToString();
            if ((textbox3.Text).Length == 10)
            {
                textbox4.Text = textbox1.Text + Environment.NewLine + textbox2.Text + Environment.NewLine + textbox3.Text; 
            }

            else 
            {
                textbox3.Text = string.Empty;
                textbox4.Text = string.Empty;
                MessageBox.Show("Please, enter a 10 digit Contact No.", "Error");
            }
        }

        catch
        {
            textbox3.Text = string.Empty;
            textbox4.Text = string.Empty;
            MessageBox.Show("Please, enter a 10 digit Contact No.", "Error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: `TryParse` and it it's ok, then use result. No need for `try/catch` then. And regarding repeatable code, have 2 local variables `newTextBox3` and `newTextBox4`, which values are `""` by default. Change them if no error. If error - show `MessageBox`. Set their values to `textbox3` and `textbox4` at the end of function always (think about it as buffered output).

Comment: Why not use the validation classes?

Comment: What if the user enters 9 digit, but negative value as a code? E.g. -123456789; it seems that this input passes the test "Convert.ToInt64(textbox3.Text)).ToString().Length = 10"

Comment: My actual purpose was to check whether it is 10 digit number or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to test whether `textbox3.Text` contains *10-digit number* your can use *regular expressions*

```
  if (Regex.IsMatch(textbox3.Text, @"^\d{10}$")) 
    textbox4.Text = textbox1.Text + Environment.NewLine + 
                    textbox2.Text + Environment.NewLine + 
                    textbox3.Text; 
  else {
    textbox3.Text = string.Empty;
    textbox4.Text = string.Empty;
    MessageBox.Show("Please, enter a 10 digit Contact No.", "Error");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems that only `Convert.ToInt64` would throw an exception, I'd probably do something like this.

```
bool error = false;
try
{       
    textbox3.Text = (Convert.ToInt64(textbox3.Text)).ToString();
}
catch
{ error = true; }

if ((textbox3.Text).Length == 10)
{
    textbox4.Text = textbox1.Text + Environment.NewLine + textbox2.Text + Environment.NewLine + textbox3.Text; 
}
else
    error = true;

if (error)
{
    textbox3.Text = string.Empty;
    textbox4.Text = string.Empty;
    MessageBox.Show("Please, enter a 10 digit Contact No.", "Error");
}
```